# SSL certificate, godaddy, JBoss AS 7

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, jboss7.x

[EDIT]

I used those two commands to generate the csr:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore XY.key
keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -file certreq.csr -keystore XY.key
```

gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt has 3 blocks in it, the other two have only 1.

[/EDIT]

I want to install the certificates. I want to use:

```
keytool -import -alias [AB] -keystore [CD.key] -trustcacerts -file [EF.crt]
```

I know CD; that's the keystore I generated, but what alias (AB) is correct for which certificate (EF)? The three certificates I get are:

b715e55ecaeeba39.crt

gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

gdig2.crt

And after I did that correctly, am I right by using the:

```
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore <your_keystore_filename> -file certreq.csr
```

The file with which I requested the Certificate?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any alias you want as long as you specify it in the `server.xml` file (parameter `keyAlias`, case sensitive).

`tomcat` seems to be the default alias : https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/ssl-howto.html

Comment: Sorry, didn't make it clear my problem is, that I don't know what to do with those 3 files. I can only import one file for an alias. Which one of those files should be imported as tomcat, and what with the other 2 files?

Comment: Two of the three certificates you are mentionning are used to build a trust chain to a root Certificat Authority (one is the root CA, the other is the intermediate CA).
The last file should be your certificate. I would love to help you, but unfortunately, I cannot do that without knowing what file corresponds to what certificate, and what steps you have taken to generate your keystore. Since certificates are public, would you mind publishing their base64 version (PEM encoding) by editing your first post ? Please also give us the command line used to create the keystore and get the CSR.

Comment: I edited the first post. Does it help or do I need to give you the content of the files (you mean the text-content by base64 | PEM encoding,or?) ?

Comment: Ok, maybe take a look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269293/how-to-import-godaddy-certificates-in-tomcat-given-gd-bundle-g2-g1-crt-gdig2-cr